# Excel auto convert cell values into Lakh decimal

Tags: excel, excel-formula, decimal, excel-2007

I want to auto convert cell values to lakh(Indian Unit) decimal

> 1) 120212 to 1.20
>
> 2) 898982 to 8.98

Is this possible with format-cell?

Comment: yes its 120213! but we need to display 1.20

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the figures , then using the following formula will do it :

```
=ROUND(A1/100000,2)
```

where the value in A1 is , to take your own example , `12538746`.

The result will be `125.39`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, specifically at the 'Answer the Question' heading.  The question asked was how to format a value to display in Lakh decimal, which isn't the question you answered.  In fact, in comments, the poster specifically noted he or she was not looking to simply convert.  Thanks for responding, and I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A method would be to use the number format - `0.00,,%\%` which does work but unfortunately adds percentage signs. This is because the commas devide by 1000 but percentages multiply by 100, so you need it to do the last devide.

You could hide the percentages by putting a carriage return in possibly, but that's probably your best bet with numberformats.

Answer (score 0):

Type 100000 in a spare cell. Copy it and paste special on the value to be converted as lacs and select divide on that. Automatically the cells which has values will get converted to lacs.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Format-Format Cell-number-custom-type **#.00,** if u wanna add Zero before, eg 5000 to read as 0.05 instead of just .05 type **0#.00,**

Answer (score 0):

Type 100000 in a spare cell. Copy it and paste special on the value to be converted as lacs and select divide on that. Automatically the cells which has values will get converted to lacs.
It was i am looking for...